How do I redirect with Cypress
So, my problem is as follows. I connect to a website where a few buttons are to be clicked, and then one of the buttons redirects to another website where the tests are mainly run. Virtually all tests run on the second website, and this can only be reached via the redirect. I've tried a few things, but I think I'm having trouble understanding the whole “redirect” issue.
    cy.origin("https://Redirectwebsite.com", () =>  {
      cy.visit("https://SiteThatShouldRedirect.com");
      cy.get('#submitConsentButton > :nth-child(2)').should("be.visible").click();
      cy.get('#oAuthLogin > :nth-child(1)').should("be.visible").click();
  });

EDIT:
I think i got it a bit. In Cypress Runner I'm on the Website I wanna get redirected to. But i cant use The Element Picker Tool from Cypress Runner. When I hover over Elements, they doesnt even get highlighted.

What's your issue exactly ? Does it not redirect on the second site or do the assertions fail ?

Are you getting redirected in your test? Or what exactly is the issue. To check if youre redirected you can check the url with cy.url()
